# How can I get the points in face mesh like eye ,eyebrow , lip, mouth ,nose using ARFaceTracking in Swift 4.2?

Tags: arkit, swift4.2, arfacegeometry

Currently i am getting the left and right eye points, How can i get the other parts points using ARFaceTracking or other framework in swift 4 in ios.

please give the feedback above the questions?

Comment: please anyone  give me a solution.

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 5):

You can use the ARFaceGeometry vertices. It’s a magic number. The ARFaceGeometry has 1220 vertices in it and index 9 is on the nose. This works.

```
let vertices = [anchor.geometry.vertices[9]] // nose

// You can use Features Indexes with array
let features = ["nose", "leftEye", "rightEye", "mouth", "hat"]
let featureIndices = [[9], [1064], [42], [24, 25], [20]]
```

Here features is an array of the node names you gave to each feature and featureIndices are the vertex indexes in the [ARFaceGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacegeometry) that correspond to those features. [ARFaceAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor) property is used.

Comment: @jesuasir Please find this code may be it will be useful >>https://www.raywenderlich.com/5491-ar-face-tracking-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started
>>https://github.com/mattlawer/FaceLandmarksDetection/tree/master/DetectFaceLandmarks

Comment: @jesuasir Also you can go through these blend shapes coefficients . Check them out in Apple’s official documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor/blendshapelocation

Comment: right eye indices go from 1085 to 1108 and left eye indices go from 1061 to 1084

Comment: @P1xelfehler You probably just saved me an hour or two. 

Answer (score 2):

Here's some magic numbers for you:

```
let mouthTopLeft = Array(250...256)
let mouthTopCenter = [24]
let mouthTopRight = Array(685...691).reversed()
let mouthRight = [684]
let mouthBottomRight = [682, 683,700,709,710,725]
let mouthBottomCenter = [25]
let mouthBottomLeft = [265,274,290,275,247,248]
let mouthLeft = [249]
let mouthClockwise : [Int] = mouthLeft +
                               mouthTopLeft + mouthTopCenter +
                               mouthTopRight + mouthRight +
                               mouthBottomRight + mouthBottomCenter +
                               mouthBottomLeft
let eyeTopLeft = Array(1090...1101)
let eyeBottomLeft = Array(1102...1108) + Array(1085...1089)
let eyeTopRight = Array(1069...1080)
let eyeBottomRight = Array(1081...1084) + Array(1061...1068)
```

Comment: But tell me luca992, where did you find these? Is it simply trial and error?

Comment: @user3069232 lol, those were found with an hour or two of my free time. So yup.